# Dynamically 301 old urls to new url pattern?

Tags: django

I have updated my url pattern from:

```
(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'bugs.views.bug_detail'),
```

to

```
(r'^issue/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'bugs.views.bug_detail'),
```

So I'm now relying on the primary key in the URL since the slug can change at any time. I have about 40-50 links that I need to 301 to spiders/crawlers.

What's the easiest way of doing a 301 within Django instead of having to hardcode the `Redirect 301`s in my Apache conf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, got it figured out. I kept the old url pattern in there and routed to `bugs.views.bug_detail_redirect` and defined a method that uses the slug and does a 301:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponsePermanentRedirect

def bug_detail_redirect(request,  slug):
    #bug = get_object_or_404(Bug,id=id)
     bug = get_object_or_404(Bug,slug=slug)
     return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(bug.get_absolute_url())
```

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-redirect-to is actually probably closer to what you're looking for.

```
from django.views.generic.simple import redirect_to

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('^foo/(?P<id>\d+)/$', redirect_to, {'url': '/bar/%(id)s/'}),
)
```

That way you don't need to clutter your views up.

Comment: That link is broken now, found it in Django 1.4 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-redirect-to